# Joined pipelines

Tags: shell-script, pipe, fifo, coprocesses

Considering a routine such as this one:

```
alpha() { echo a b c |tr ' ' '\n'; }
```

which outputs a stream, I would like to take the output stream, transform it, and `paste` it with the original output stream.

If I take use upcasing as a sample transformation, I can achieve what I want with:

```
$ mkfifo p1 p2
$ alpha | tee p1 >( tr a-z A-Z > p2) >/dev/null &
$ paste p1 p2
a       A
b       B
c       C
```

My question is, is there a better way to do this, preferably one not involving named pipes?

Comment: You know, I was working on a more flexible sort of process substitution imitation the other day. I think it's still open in the editor. Maybe I'll see if I can finish it right now. By the way, there is *nothing* wrong with named pipes. Try `mkfifo pipe; { rm pipe; cat < file; } >pipe` and in another terminal do `cat pipe`.

Comment: I put the pipe thing here.

Answer (score 6):

In most unices you can reference a file descriptor by its device link.

```sh
alpha(){ echo a b c | tr \  \\n; }
alpha | { alpha |
    tr \[:lower:] \[:upper:] |
    paste - /dev/fd/9
}   9<&0
```

---

```
A   a
B   b
C   c
```

---

#### named pipes

---

Ok, so I did have a pretty well working version of this already. The version open in my editor *(as yet unfinished)* is not currently workable - I kind of tore the whole option parsing bit to pieces and only vaguely remember my intent. But this...

```sh
_p(){   : "$((_$$=0))"
    cd -P -- "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}"          &&
    while   [ -h "$$.$((_$$+=$$))" ]    ||
            [ -e "$$.$((_$$))" ]
    do :;   done                        &&
    mkfifo  -m a-w,u=rwx "$$.$((_$$))"  &&
    printf  %s "$PWD/$$.$((_$$))"       &&
    exec    >&- >&0                     &&
    case    $1 in
    (+)     shift
            eval "  rm $$.$((_$$))
                    cd - >/dev/null
            $@" < "$$.$((_$$))" &;;
    (-)     shift
            eval "  rm $$.$((_$$))
                    cd - >/dev/null
            $@" >   "$$.$((_$$))"   &;;
    (*) set --
        : "${1:?"USAGE: [-+] [cmd args...]"}"
    esac
}   <&- <>/dev/null
```

You'll likely notice there's some really weird stuff going on with `$((_$$))`. It's a kinduva a hacky way to attempt to step on the command's environment as little as I can. I try very hard here to keep *all* possible environment values as pristine as I might, because the point of this function is to do much the same as what process substitution does - run an arbitrary command that writes to a pipe.

```sh
cat "$(_p - echo a b c)"
```

---

```
a b c
```

Here's a simplified version of the workflow:

```sh
mkfifo pipe                         # make a pipe
printf %s\\n "$PWD/pipe"            # substitute its file name
exec <&- </dev/null >&- >/dev/null  # break cmd sub i/o
eval "rm pipe;$@" >pipe &           # eval rm; args
```

Because the `eval` command wraps all of its arguments in a single simple command, `eval`'s stdout is the entire `eval`'d command group's stdout. And it is the *shell* which owns that pipe descriptor and not any of its child processes which merely inherit it as stdout. And so the shell does the `open()` - and because we do a *blocking* `open()` *(like `>` rather than `<>`)* the shell hangs until that pipe gets a reader.

This means that `rm` does not execute - cannot be executed - until some other process establishes a read file descriptor for that pipe. When some process opens it for reading *(as `cat` does above)* the shell stops hanging, and the first action that is taken is the pipe is `rm`'d - before anything else. This is *not* a problem - the pipe *already* has a reader process and a writer process. All is well.

It's a little buggy. For example:

```sh
echo "$(_p -)"
```

---

```
/tmp/6023.6023
```

^*That* pipe does not get `rm`'d. `echo` doesn't read it. So `eval`'s still waiting. To kill it:

```
: </tmp/6023.6023
```

...is enough to kill it, though.

Stuff like this is what I use it for:

```sh
exec 9<> "$(_p -)"
sed -ue's/sed/mikeserv/' <&9 &
echo hi sed >&9
```

---

```
hi mikeserv
```

By the way, I've only shown the `<()` equivalent, but `>()` can be simulated like...

```sh
echo hi sed >"$(_p + sed -e's/sed/mikeserv/' '>&2')"
```

---

```
hi mikeserv
```

---

#### other pipes

---

You don't need my hacky function for this. Process substitution is pretty widespread. And there's nothing to stop you *keeping* your pipe when you ask for one - you needn't immediately assign it and discard it.

*(Paranoid note: I kind of hate it because I never know where those files **come from** - chances are you're a more well-adjusted individual and so the following is acceptable to you)*

```sh
eval "exec 9<> " <(:)
```

There's a pipe - it's all yours. There's no cleanup required. You're good to go.

---

#### `_pp` - hehe

---

```sh
_pp(){  :   "$((_$$=0))"
        _e()    case    ${1:-0} in
                (i|0)   exec >&- 1<>/dev/null;;
                (o|1) ! exec <&-  <>/dev/null;;
                (e|[2-9])
                        exec <&-  <>/dev/null >&- >&0
                        set     "${1#e}"
                        return  "${1:-2}";;
                (*[\<\>]*)
                        eval "
                        exec <&-  <>/dev/null >&- >&0 $1"
                esac
        cd -P   -- "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}"            &&
        while   [ -h "$$.$((_$$+=1))" ]         ||
                [ -e "$$.$((_$$))"    ]
        do :;   done                            && 
        mkfifo  -m a-w,u=rwx   "$$.$((_$$))"    &&
        printf  "%s/%s" "$PWD" "$$.$((_$$))"    &&
        case    $1  in
        (+*)    set \> \< "$@"  ;;
        (-*)    set \< \> "$@"  ;;
        (*)     rm  "$$.$((_$$))"
                set ''  USAGE:  '<-+>[+-[fd][file]]'
                ${1:?"$(printf "\n%s\t%s [cmd...]$@")"};;
        esac    &&
        case    $3  in
        (?|?[ioe0-9])
                _e  "${3#?}"
                eval "exec $1&$?";;
        (?/*)   _e "$1"'"$2"' "${3#?}";;
        (*)     _e "$1"'"$2"' "$OLDPWD/${3#?}"
        esac    &&
        eval "  shift 3
                eval \" rm $$.$((_$$))
                        cd - >/dev/null
        \$@\"   $2$$.$((_$$)) &"
}
```

...so... I finally got around to making `_p` im*p*roved workable. The `[-+]` options can take any of *`ioe`* options to mean *`std(in|out|err)`* *(though `stdout` is pretty useless in the command sub)* or *`[0-9]`* to reference any descriptors you may have already setup, or anything else to be interpreted as any arbitrary filename. When called with `+` the argument is understood to be an out stream - as input is supposed to come from the command you call it with - and with `-` the argument is used as input.

And so, with this, the last `sed` above might be written like:

```sh
echo hi sed >"$(_pp +2 sed s/sed/mikeserv/)"
```

---

```
hi mikeserv
```