# How to send all output to `logger` in POSIX shell?

Tags: shell, pipe, posix

I'd like to log standard output and standard error separately in `.xprofile` using `logger`. In Bash I think that would look something like this:

```
exec 1> >(logger --priority user.notice --tag $(basename $0)) \
     2> >(logger --priority user.error --tag $(basename $0))
```

How would I do that in a <strike>POSIX</strike> **`/bin/sh`** compatible manner?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no POSIX equivalent. You can only perform a redirection with `exec`, not a fork. A pipe requires a fork, and the shell waits for the child to finish.

One solution is to put all your code in a function.

```
all_my_code () {
  …
}
{ all_my_code |
  logger --priority user.notice --tag "$(basename "$0")"; } 2>&1 | 
  logger --priority user.error --tag "$(basename "$0")"
```

(This also logs any error from the stdout instance of logger to the stderr instance. You can avoid this with more file descriptor shuffling.)

If you want the parent shell to exit even if the `logger` processes are still running, put `&` at the end of the `logger` invocations.

```
{ all_my_code |
  logger --priority user.notice --tag "$(basename "$0")" & } 2>&1 | 
  logger --priority user.error --tag "$(basename "$0")" &
```

Alternatively, you can use named pipes.

```
pipe_dir=$(mktemp -d)
mkfifo "$pipe_dir/out" "$pipe_dir/err"
<"$pipe_dir/out" logger --priority user.notice --tag "$(basename "$0")" &
<"$pipe_dir/err" logger --priority user.error --tag "$(basename "$0")" &
exec >"$pipe_dir/out" 2>"$pipe_dir/err" 
…
rm -r "$pipe_dir"
```

Comment: That will appear in syslog as two entries (out & err) for the whole script. The example in the question will have one (or two) entry per command.

Comment: @DarkHeart I don't understand your comment. The code in the question and both solutions I propose run the same number of instances of `logger` and pass the same input to each of them.

Comment: sorry, my mistake

Comment: [This seems simpler](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/commit/70f4705e87dfa693d7537b9825089d9ccfec6ace), so I'm going with your named pipes solution.

Answer (score 11):

#### POSIX command/process substitution

---

```sh
_log()( x=0
    while  [ -e "${TMPDIR:=/tmp}/$$.$((x+=1))" ]
    do     continue; done        &&
    mkfifo -- "$TMPDIR/$$.$x"    &&
    printf %s\\n "$TMPDIR/$$.$x" || exit
    exec >&- >/dev/null
    {  rm -- "$TMPDIR/$$.$x"
       logger --priority user."$1" --tag "${0##*/}"
    }  <"$TMPDIR/$$.$x" &
)   <&- </dev/null
```

You should be able to use that like:

```
exec >"$(_log notice)" 2>"$(_log error)"
```

Here's a version which makes use of the `mktemp` command:

```
_log()( p=
    mkfifo "${p:=$(mktemp -u)}"    &&
    printf %s "$p"                 &&
    exec  <&- >&- <>/dev/null >&0  &&
    {   rm "$p"
        logger --priority user."$1" --tag "${0##*/}"
    }   <"$p" &
)
```

...which does much the same, except that it allows `mktemp` to select the filename for you. This works because *process substitution* is by no means magical and works in a very similar way to *command substitution*. Instead of replacing the expansion with the value of the command run within it as *command substitution* does, *process substitution* replaces it with the name of a filesystem link where the output can be found.

While the POSIX shell does not provide a direct corollary to such a thing, emulating it is very simply done. All you need to do is make a file, print its name to the standard out of a command substitution, and in the background of same run your command which will output to that file. Now you can just redirect into the value of that expansion - *exactly* as you do with process substitution. And so the POSIX shell provides all of the tools you need of course - all that is required is that you put them to use in a way which suits you.

Both of the above versions ensure that they destroy the filesystem link to the pipes they create/use before ever making use of them. This means there is no cleanup required after the fact, and, more importantly, their streams are only available to the processes which initially open them - and so their filesystem links cannot be used as a means to snoop/hijack your logging activity. To leave their fs-links in the filesystem is a potential security hole.

---

Another way is to wrap it. It can be done from within the script.

```sh
x=${x##*[!0-9]*}
_log(){ 
    logger --priority user."$1" --tag "${0##*/}"
}   2>/dev/null >&2

cd ../"$PPID.$x" 2>/dev/null &&
trap 'rm -rf -- "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/$PPID.$x"' 0 || 
{   until cd -- "${TMPDIR:=/tmp}/$$.$x"
    do    mkdir -- "$TMPDIR/$$.$((x+=1))"
    done  && 
    x=$x "$0" "$@" | _log notice
    exit
}   2>&1 | _log error
```

That would basically allow your script to call itself if it hasn't yet and get you a work directory in temp to boot.

Comment: [Done](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/commit/74ea2080ed923368e176ccfcd757adb5c985ab0d), thank you!

Comment: @l0b0 - I'm just about to update [another one](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/218252/52934) kind of like this... It's more general purposed, and I finally got around to giving it the ability to handle some options as are related to i/o descriptors/files.

Comment: @l0b0 - if you wanted to use `mktemp` and other non-standard commands, it could be: `_log()( p=; mkfifo "${p:=$(mktemp -u)}"; printf %s "$p"; exec <&- >&- <>/dev/null >&0; { rm "$p"; logger --priority user."$1"  --tag "${0##*/}"; } <"$p" &)`. I wrote it using fully portable command language in all ways - with the exception of your own. Also, `basename` is not a very useful utility. `"${0##*/}"` is both more robust and faster.

Comment: I changed it because I only need it to work on modern platforms; the main issue was that `.xprofile` *has* to be executed with `sh`.

Comment: @l0b0 - in that case you could just symlink your shell of choice somewhere to `sh` and modify `$PATH` to match in `.xprofile`. Maybe reconsider your edit though - `/bin/sh` is, as I think, maybe a little more ambiguous.

Comment: The instant I saw the first code block I thought, "mikeserv wrote that."  :)

Comment: This is actually completely brilliant code; I think it's great.  One issue, though: [POSIX `logger` doesn't recognize any options](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/logger.html).  But, since POSIX `logger` doesn't even have a way to log standard input (only command line arguments), the whole effort comes to pieces without an extended version of `logger`.  Perhaps the same effect could be achieved with `tee -a` but then we're chest-deep in hypotheticals; I don't personally know any implementations of `logger` that don't accept any options.

Comment: @Wildcard - yeah, I did. What about the options?  don't handle any here becuase I didn't really care about the `logger` thing - this was just intended to demonstrate a few simply implemented and highly customizable library functions to handle process substitution with little fuss and much speed in tiny POSIX shells so people wouldn't have to turn to giant, buggy sloths like `bash`. A lot of my other stuff is written with similar spirit.

Comment: @mikeserv, one thing I'm not getting in your first example, is how do you ensure the `exec` command in the top level actually opens the `fifo` for writing before the `rm` command is run?  (Also, is there some edge case breakage that is prevented by closing stdin/stdout before redirecting them from/to `/dev/null`?)

Comment: @Wildcard - just a minute and i'll try to sort out the first part of the question, but the answer to the second is yes: the edge case is a `zsh` w/ multios enabled. As for the first part: `{ this; can\'t; happen; before; } < this`. Does that help?