# bash process substitution with temporary file

Tags: bash, shell, tmp, process-substitution

Some programs needs their files to be seekable, for example `objdump` does.

```
$ objdump -D -b binary -m i8086 <(echo 0xea 0x5b 0xe0 0x00 0xf0|xxd -r -p)
objdump: Warning: '/proc/self/fd/11' is not an ordinary file
```

It would be convenient to have process substitution use temporary files.

I can see in the man page that bash can fallback to temporary files with process substitution, but can I explicitly ask him to use temporary files?

Like `zsh`'s `=()`.

```
$ objdump -D -b binary -m i8086 =(echo 0xea 0x5b 0xe0 0x00 0xf0|xxd -r -p)

/tmp/zsh1u1Nrw:     file format binary


Disassembly of section .data:

00000000 <.data>:
   0:   ea 5b e0 00 f0          ljmp   $0xf000,$0xe05b
```

Comment: I doubt it, but you can always use `mktemp`.

Comment: Maybe you should try compile `bash` with `HAVE_DEV_FD` set to `0`.

Comment: @Wildcard I don't see how mktemp helps. It won't remove the file automatically. I might as well just do `foo >/tmp/xxx;cmd /tmp/xx;rm /tmp/xxx` It's not about bash programming, for which there are better solutiosn, but about one off one-line scripts.

Comment: @cuonglm that would make bash always use temporary files, which is not what I want (not to mention that home baked bash is not a great idea).

Comment: You could use a seekable *here  string* instead: `objdump -D -b binary -m i8086 /dev/stdin <<<$(echo 0xea 0x5b 0xe0 0x00 0xf0|xxd -r -p)`

Comment: You might be interested in mikeserv's [POSIX functions for process substitution using `mkfifo` and `mktemp`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/218505/135943).

Comment: @Wildcard I might be, but I can't see why is it related to my question. Would you enlighten me? As I said, one can already do `cmd >x;cmd2 x;rm x`, and I don't see the difference

Comment: Oops. The *here string* version silently drops the null char!

Comment: @ElazarLeibovich for one thing, as mikeserv pointed out in that answer: "Both of the above versions ensure that they destroy the filesystem link to the pipes they create/use before ever making use of them. This means there is no cleanup required after the fact, and, more importantly, their streams are only available to the processes which initially open them - and so their filesystem links cannot be used as a means to snoop/hijack your logging activity. To leave their fs-links in the filesystem is a potential security hole."

Comment: @Wildcard using fifo is not possible with `objdump`, that's the whole point of the question. Otherwise `<()` was good enough.

Comment: I did get that.  I am quite certain you could modify the code I linked to to make it use `touch` instead of `mkfifo`.  (Just doing that change by itself would probably be enough.)

Comment: @Wildcard as I previously said. This is not a programming problem. I already said that `cmd >x;objdump x;rm x` is the best approach, mktemp is not really needed. I wanted a solution that is convenient for one off scripts.

Answer (score 3):

Based on meuh's comment; apparently bash here-strings can be abused as temporary files, try this:

```
( echo 0xea 0x5b 0xe0 0x00 0xf0 | 
  xxd -r -p >/dev/fd/9; objdump -D -b binary -m i8086 /dev/fd/9) 9<<<''
```

Comment: The trick is that *here documents* and *here strings* use temporary files [under the hood](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/redir.c?h=bash-4.3&id=ac50fbac377e32b98d2de396f016ea81e8ee9961#n448) (replace `objdump ...` with `stat /dev/fd/9` to see, it won't be a problematic FIFO or a pipe, but a symlink to a file in `/tmp` or `$TMPDIR`).

Comment: I used your answer's method for my `objdump` situation. Interestingly, it only worked for me with `gcc -o /dev/fd/9 [ . . . ]`, not with `gcc >&9 -o - [ . . . ]`. I was going to write an answer (not to the objdump situation, but for a non-null-sensitive situation) that used a here document with a command substitution, but then I saw that you had already mentioned a here string in the question comments, which is even better.

Comment: In bash 5.2 this does not work any more for small heredoc strings, as bash may internally use a pipe, instead of a file. See function [here_document_to_fd](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/redir.c?h=bash-5.2&id=74091dd4e8086db518b30df7f222691524469998).