# How do you implement process substitution (using a bash script) in a shell that doesn't have it?

Tags: process-substitution, mksh

I've seen Fish shell implement process substitution as a function:

```
# === Fish shell lang:
function psub
   mkfifo $the_pipe
   cat >$the_pipe &
   echo $the_pipe
   # remove pipe when bg job is done
end  

# Example:
diff (echo abc | psub)  (echo def | psub)
```

Full code: https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/blob/master/share/functions/psub.fish

I've tried for several hours to re-implement it for a non-Fish shell (mksh), but could not do it:

```
# Executable file:  my.psub.sh
the_pipe="$(mktemp /tmp/pipe.XXXXXXXXXX)"
mkfifo $the_pipe
cat >$the_pipe &
echo $the_pipe

# Example:
diff $(echo abc | my.psub.sh)  $(echo def | my.psub.sh)
```

The command blocks. I've tried everything I could think of, but I have no idea where to go next.

Comment: are you looking for `diff <(echo abc)  <(echo def )` in bash  ? (and fish example is not working for me)

Comment: Yes. Bash implements '<()' as proc. sub. which is non-standard for POSIX.  For the fish example: this is what I get: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Cett6VoXIAAdpcN.jpg:large (function psub is already defined by Fish in each Fish shell you start.)

Comment: OK, I didn't get you want to avoid bash. (yet you use $( )'s substitution for temporary file, is that posix ? )

Comment: It's called "command substitution": $() . I'm not sure if it's standard POSIX. However, the shell I'm using (mksh) implements it.   <() is the "process substitution"

Comment: Apparantly, this question was asked by someone else on the Android StackExchange: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/101839/work-around-for-process-substitution-in-mksh

Comment: @dgo.a: Read http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/218505/38906

Comment: @Archemar yes, `$(…)` is POSIX and, in fact, highly recommended over the older form that used an accent gravis for substitution, as it defines a full recursive shell and quoting environment.

Comment: @cuonglm Thanks for that link. For output it works great:   `cmd >$(log_it ..) 2>$(log it ...)`.  But, it doesn't seem to work for my example w/`diff`: `diff  $( proc | proc )  $( proc | proc)`. The `diff` won't run until the subshells exit. In my case, diff needs the output of the subshells. But, I also need to cleanup named pipes. The problem is the subshells need to exit, preventing the cleanup of the named pipes.

Comment: In my experiment (code slightly changed from yours), it’s diff which blocks. It reads `abc` from the FIFO, then wants to read more from it. At this time, it should be signalled EOF but isn’t. I’m currently investigating why. -- mksh author here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s a bit difficult but doable:

```
function die {
        print -ru2 -- "E: $*"
        exit 1
}

function psubin {
        local stdin=$(cat; echo .) pipe

        pipe=$(mktemp /tmp/psub.XXXXXXXXXX) || die mktemp

        # this is racy
        rm -f "$pipe"
        mkfifo "$pipe" || die mkfifo

        (
                # don’t block parent
                exec <&- >&- 2>&-
                # write content to FIFO
                print -nr -- "${stdin%.}" >"$pipe"
                # signal EOF to reader, ensure it’s not merged
                sleep 0.1
                :>"$pipe"
                # clean up
                (sleep 1; rm -f "$pipe") &
        ) &
        print -nr -- "$pipe"
}

diff -u $(echo abc | psubin) $(echo def | psubin)
```

The problems you and I encountered here are:

- `mkfifo` complains unless you `rm` `mktemp`’s output first
- mksh blocks for the background process if it still shares any file descriptors (stdin, stdout, stderr) with the parent (Note: This is probably the only valid use case for using `>&-` instead of `>/dev/null`, and only because we can guarantee these fds to no longer be used, nor replaced by any new fds)
- as we don’t have stdin in the background process we’ll need to cache its content, byte-exact
- EOF with FIFOs (named pipes) is nontrivial. Let’s just leave at that… (we could do some tricks with trying to open the FIFO non-blocking to check if there’s a reader, and signal EOF until the reader died, but this works well enough **for now**)
- it’s nicer if the FIFO is removed after use…

On the other hand: good thing we’re doing this now, because I eventually will wish to implement `<(…)` into mksh itself, and then I need to know what to watch out for, since we can’t use `/dev/fd/` as GNU bash does, because that’s not portable enough.

Comment: Thank you so much. This has answered other questions I had about `mksh` and processes. (I asked the question for esoteric reasons. `mksh` has been more reliable and predictable than other shells... and a joy to use even w/o process substitution.)

Answer (score -1):

This doesn't seem possible:

```
 diff   (echo abc | ./my.psub.sh)    (echo def | ./my.psub.sh)
```

It blocks as the 2 sub-shells need to exit before `diff` is run.

It's doable on the Fish shell, but most likely because they do things like command and process substitution [very differently](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/2867#issuecomment-203185395) with [it's own set of problems](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/1040).

An alternative would be to use `busybox` as suggested over in "[Work-around for process substitution in mksh](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/101839/work-around-for-process-substitution-in-mksh)":

```
busybox diff =(sort ./a) =(sort ./b)
```