# How can I send stdout to multiple commands in fish shell?

Tags: shell, command-line, pipe, io-redirection, fish

Same question as [How can I send stdout to multiple commands?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28503/how-can-i-send-stdout-to-multiple-commands) but for fish shell.

Comment: Linking: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/272838/117549

Comment: You'll use the [`psub`](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#psub) command instead of the bash `>(...)` syntax

Comment: @glennjackman can you provide the fish equivalent of bash `cat file.txt | tee >(pbcopy) >(do_stuff) >(do_more_stuff) | grep errors`?

Comment: I linked to the documentation. Is it unclear?

Comment: @glennjackman From the documentation I know how to replace `<(x)` with `(x | psub)` but I have no idea how to replace `>(x)`. Anyway why don't you post you comment as an answer?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the intent of your comment. `>(x)` isn't implemented yet: https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/1786